# Enlarge signature field size

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I would like to know if there is an option to enlarge the signature field's size on the esignature forms when it is loaded. The field should not be resizable for the user, perhaps should be enlarged to a fixed size when the form is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change the size of the SignHere tab, you can change sizes of other tabs like the Text tab for example.